# Passing args and kwargs to base python object

Tags: python, inheritance, keyword-argument, python-dataclasses

I have some data I need to marshal, of which there are two main types with some base behavior.  In order to avoid all the duplicate logic of *actually* marshaling the data, I decided to use inheritance.  I figured objects would also be a good choice since I can add type hints, and make all the arguments required (say vs. a `dict`, which is what we are currently using and is prone to typos/field omission).
I am also aware of `TypedDict` but since there is a tiny bit of behavior associated with the data I didn't feel it would be a good choice.  A `dataclass` seems like a good middle ground except it's not so great with inheritance and exposes some fields that should remain hidden from the caller.
All I really care about is enforcing required arguments and types.

So let's say I have these classes

```
class Base:
    def __init__(self, id: str, **kwargs):
        self.id = id # the caller doesn't need to know about this field.
        # data really just needs to be collected into this dict with arg names as keys
        self.properties = kwargs or {}


class A(Base):
    def __init__(self, a: str, b: str, c: datetime):
        super().__init__(foo_id, a=a, b=b, c=c)
```

This is fine when there are three arguments, but some have ten, and there's just a ton of boilerplate.  Is there a way to remove all the arg passing to `Base`, or even just collect `args` into `kwargs` and pass that down?

Comment: This seems backwards. The usual advice is that each class defines the specific arguments they expect, and accept arbitrary keyword arguments that it will pass on to `super().__init__`, assuming that *somebody* upstream wants them.

Comment: The question is, who requires `a`, `b`, and `c`, `A`, or `Base`? If `A`,it should just add them to `self.properties` itself. (The `dict` is guaranteed to exist after `super().__init__` returns.)

Answer (score 1):

A class should extract the keyword arguments it expects, and pass the rest upstream, assuming that *somebody* needs them. It's the caller's responsibility to pass all required arguments.

```
class Base:
    def __init__(self, *, id: str, **kwargs):
        super.__init__(**kwargs)
        self.id = id
        self.properties = {}

class A(Base):
    def __init__(self, *, a: str, b: str, c: datetime, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(**kwargs)
        # self.properties is guaranteed to exist at this point
        self.properties['a'] = a
        self.properties['b'] = b
        self.properties['c'] = c

a = A(id=foo_id, a="baz", b="bar", c=datetime.datetime.now())
```

If you really want `A.__init__` to hard-code `foo_id` as the `id` attribute for `Base`, you can:

```
class A(Base):
    def __init__(self, *, a: str, b: str, c: datetime, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(id=foo_id, **kwargs)
        self.properties['a'] = a
        self.properties['b'] = b
        self.properties['c'] = c

a = A(a="baz", b="bar", c=datetime.datetime.now())
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use the default method of passing all arguments in python:

```py
class A(Base):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs) -> None:
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
```

This is standard python to catch and then pass all arguments.

However, separate question for you: are you needing to define your own init processing steps?

...In your example above, your child class's `init` isn't doing anything except calling the parent's `init`.

If you *don't* define an `__init__` method in a child class, when an instance is created python will automatically call `__init__` in the parent class.  *So you don't need to define `init` anywhere **unless** you need to for some class specific steps*.

Eg:

```py
class Base: 
    def __init__(self, arg1 = "argument one"): 
        self.arg1 = arg1 
     
         
class Derived(Base): 
    pass 
     
b = Base() 
print b.arg1 
 
d = Derived() 
print d.arg1 

# output:
argument one 
argument one
```